# How to update multiple elements conditionally at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and trying to figure out what the best way is to update multiple elements at once without having to repeat code all the time.

I got a login page, that has several states: "LOGIN", "SIGNUP" or "FORGOT_PASSWORD". Depending on the current mode, I am already able to change the used form with renderForm(). However, I also need to update some other text in the root component but don't know what the most efficient way is to do so. Of course I could repeat renderForm() for every text snippet I have to change but this seems not very DRY.

This is my (very simplified) code:

```
function Login() {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState("LOGIN");

    function renderForm(): ReactElement {
    return (
      <>
        {
          {
            LOGIN: <EmailPasswordForm setMode={setMode} type="login"/>,
            SIGNUP: <EmailPasswordForm setMode={setMode} type="signup"/>,
            FORGOT_PASSWORD: <ForgotPassword setMode={setMode} auth={auth} />,
          }[mode]
        }
      </>
    );
  }


    return (
    <div>
        <h2>
            Sign in to your account //title that needs to change depending on the mode
        </h2>

        {renderForm()}

        <a href="/privacy">Privacy Info</a>
        <p>
            Some text that also needs to change depending on if the mode is "LOGIN", "SIGNUP", or "FORGOT_PASSWORD"
        </p>
        <OAuthSignUpComponents/>
        <p>
            Some  more text that needs to change depending on if the mode is "LOGIN", "SIGNUP", or "FORGOT_PASSWORD"
        </p>
    </div>
    )
}

function EmailPasswordForm({setMode, type}) {

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        type == "login" ? loginLogic() : signupLogic();
    }

    return(
        <form>
            <input type="email/>
            <input type="password"/>
            <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            { type == "login" ? <button onClick={setMode("SIGNUP")>Sign up instead</button> : <button onClick={setMode("LOGIN")>Sign in instead</button> }
        </form>
    )
}

function ForgotPasswordForm({setMode}) {
    return(
        <form>
            <input type="email/>
            <button type="button">
        </form>
    )
}
```

One thing I tried is to use a switch in renderForm() like this:

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState("Sign in to your account");

function renderForm(){
    switch(mode) {
        case "LOGIN":
            setTitle("Sign in to your account")
            return <EmailPasswordForm setMode={setMode} type="login"/>;
        case "SIGNUP":
            setTitle("Sign in to your account")
            return <EmailPasswordForm setMode={setMode} type="signup"/>;
        case "FORGOT_PASSWORD":
            setTitle("Reset Password")
            return <ForgotPasswordForm setMode={setMode}/>
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work either as it results in a too many rerenders error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the setTitle in an effect in order for there to be no more rendering issues as you shouldn't have side-effets in your main render function, only in callbacks and effects. You can definitely keep the render form as an object instead of a switch case, as well. Either way would work.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    switch(mode) {
        case "LOGIN":
            setTitle("Sign in to your account")
        case "SIGNUP":
            setTitle("Sign in to your account")
        case "FORGOT_PASSWORD":
            setTitle("Reset Password")
    }
    return () => {
        // You can then set the original title of the application to clean up once they've logged in.
        // setTitle('Original Title')
    }
}, [mode])

function renderForm(){
    switch(mode) {
        case "LOGIN":
            return <EmailPasswordForm setMode={setMode} type="login"/>;
        case "SIGNUP":
            return <EmailPasswordForm setMode={setMode} type="signup"/>;
        case "FORGOT_PASSWORD":
            return <ForgotPasswordForm setMode={setMode}/>
    }
}
```

You don't even have to have your switch case or your object in an internal function either.

```
  const formMap={
    LOGIN: <EmailPasswordForm setMode={setMode} type="login"/>,
    SIGNUP: <EmailPasswordForm setMode={setMode} type="signup"/>,
    FORGOT_PASSWORD: <ForgotPassword setMode={setMode} auth={auth} />,
  };

  return(<div>
    <h2>
        Sign in to your account //title that needs to change depending on the mode
    </h2>

    {formMap[mode]}

    <a href="/privacy">Privacy Info</a>
    <p>
        Some text that also needs to change depending on if the mode is "LOGIN", "SIGNUP", or "FORGOT_PASSWORD"
    </p>
    <OAuthSignUpComponents/>
    <p>
        Some  more text that needs to change depending on if the mode is "LOGIN", "SIGNUP", or "FORGOT_PASSWORD"
    </p>
</div>)
```